# Magento email templates based upon customer group and payment method

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.7

Is it possible to have different email templates based upon customer groups and payment methods?

I know I can set different templates up in Conf->Transactional Emails and I can also see I can assign different templates to different sales emails in Conf-> Sales Emails. However I cant see where I can set different email templates up based upon customer groups and payment methods.

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0):

For change different email template according to customer group

Follow the below step

1.Create your email template and place it in template folder.For my case it was "app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales".

2.Create your new module. Define email template at config.xml .

```
<global>
...
<template>
<email>
<custom_email_customorder_new module="sales">
     <label>custom email module</label>
     <file>sales/order_new_custom.html</file>
     <type>html</type>
</custom_email_customorder_new>
<custom_email_customorder_log module="sales">
    <label>custom email module</label>
    <file>sales/order_log_custom.html</file>
    <type>html</type>
</custom_email_customorder_log>
</email>
</template>
... 
</global>
```

3.Extend "Sales/Model/Order.php" and overwrite the method sendNewOrderEmail()

```
 $paymentMethodCOde=$this->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    if($paymentMethodCOde=="checkmo"){
     $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
            $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
            $mailer->setTemplateId('custom_email_customorder_new');
            $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                    'order'        => $this,
                    'password'  => $password,
                    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
                )
            );
            $mailer->send();
    }elseif($paymentMethodCOde="cashondelivery"){
         $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
            $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
            $mailer->setTemplateId('custom_email_customorder_log');
            $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                    'order'        => $this,
                    'password'  => $password,
                    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
                )
            );
            $mailer->send();

    }
     else
     {
         $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
            $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
            /* magento default  sales template*/
            $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
            $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                    'order'        => $this,
                    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
                )
            );
            $mailer->send();
     }
```